# iOS app built with Xamarin has server 0.10.1 installed and added to project but calabash seems to think it is running 0.9.169

Tags: calabash-ios

We are building an app for iOS using Visual Studio and Xamarin. In the solution components, Visual Studio shows Calabash-ios versions 0.9.169, 0.10.0 and 0.10.1 as available. Only version 0.10.1 is added to the project. When I run my calabash tests on my iPad, I see warning text:

WARN: The server version is not compatible with gem version.
Please update your server.
https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/B1-Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version
       gem version: '0.10.1'
min server version: '0.10.1'
    server version: '0.9.169'

The information at the address given appears to be Xcode specific. There is nothing called calabash.framework in the solution.

Is there some equivalent to this step: '1. do a deep clean of your Xcode project' or something similar that we need to run to prevent the app from building with the old server version?

Update: after updating the device to iOS8 and updating the project to target iOS8, this is what I get when I try to use calabash:

```
irb(main):001:0> start_test_server_in_background
2014-09-25 11:31:09.767 instruments[447:1007] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'iPad (v8.0)' (The service is invalid.)
2014-09-25 11:31:09.931 instruments[447:2007] Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'iPad (v8.0)' (The service is invalid.)
Errno::EINTR: Interrupted system call - /var/folders/f3/0b6tvs5x0p3dx4j91gp3x33nrc1cvb/T/run_loop20140925-436-1vamn4b/repl-cmd.pipe
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.3/lib/run_loop/core.rb:206:in `initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.3/lib/run_loop/core.rb:206:in `open'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.3/lib/run_loop/core.rb:206:in `run_with_options'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.3/lib/run_loop/core.rb:665:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:687:in `block in new_run_loop'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:685:in `times'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:685:in `new_run_loop'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:570:in `relaunch'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/core.rb:805:in `start_test_server_in_background'
from (irb):1
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

irb(main):002:0>

Update: I have verified that the server version and the client version of Calabash-ios are both 10.1 and I still get these errors:

```
### Starting on 36071058c0deb1fb11cffe178aa2ef268f5b8e30 App: <appname> ###
2014-09-30 08:39:14 +1300 xcrun instruments -w "36071058c0deb1fb11cffe178aa2ef268f5b8e30" -D "/var/folders/f3/0b6tvs5x0p3dx4j91gp3x33nrc1cvb/T/run_loop20140930-448-ofaiqy/trace" -t "Automation" "<appname>" -e UIARESULTSPATH /var/folders/f3/0b6tvs5x0p3dx4j91gp3x33nrc1cvb/T/run_loop20140930-448-ofaiqy -e UIASCRIPT /var/folders/f3/0b6tvs5x0p3dx4j91gp3x33nrc1cvb/T/run_loop20140930-448-ofaiqy/_run_loop.js  &> /var/folders/f3/0b6tvs5x0p3dx4j91gp3x33nrc1cvb/T/run_loop20140930-448-ofaiqy/run_loop.out
Interrupted system call - /var/folders/f3/0b6tvs5x0p3dx4j91gp3x33nrc1cvb/T/run_loop20140930-448-ofaiqy/repl-cmd.pipe (Errno::EINTR)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.3/lib/run_loop/core.rb:206:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.3/lib/run_loop/core.rb:206:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.3/lib/run_loop/core.rb:206:in `run_with_options'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.3/lib/run_loop/core.rb:665:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:687:in `block in new_run_loop'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:685:in `times'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:685:in `new_run_loop'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:570:in `relaunch'
/Volumes/Projects/Enlighten/LIC/LIC.Datamate/Calabash tests/features/support/01_launch.rb:41:in `Before'
```

At each scenario, the app starts and then closes straight away.

More info: We have tried running the tests on two different Mac Minis and with two different iPads, and also with the simulator. None of them ran. We also ran the calabash console using a different app that was still on server version 1.9.169 and everything went as expected. So it seems that the issue is confined to server version 1.10.1.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a lot of testing with iOS 8 and it is definitely supported with Calabash. However, there are a couple of important issues and things to be aware of.

1) First you want to make sure you're always running the latest version of the Calabash component:

https://components.xamarin.com/view/calabash?version=10.1

Be aware that we're changing the name to Xamarin Test Cloud Agent from version 10.2.

2) If you update your project with that component and do a clean build you should be able to launch the app in debug mode in the simulator and run the command: `curl http://localhost:37265/version` to see version 0.10.1

3) I notice that you mention "iPad (v8.0)" so it seems your're running on device. That is OK, but which exact command are you using to run cucumber or calabash console? It is important to specify the DEVICE_TARGET environment variable or using: start_test_server_in_background(device_target:'DEVICE_UDID', app:'com.company.mybundleid')

4) When you try all of the above, please do one more thing. Set the following environment variables before you run your commands:

export DEBUG=1
export DEBUG_HTTP=1

and show us the exact command used to start the testing.

5) Make sure you've rebooted your Mac at least once after installing Xcode 6

Comment: Thanks Karl,
I have verified that the versions of Calabash being run on both the server and the machine running the tests is 10.1, but I am still getting errors when I run the tests:

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the name change. Looks like it came a bit earlier than 10.2!
It's already changed in 10.1.1

Comment: The problem turned out to be UIAutomation was not enabled in Settings.app > Developer > Enable UIAutomation.